# Swift: how could I draw lines inside UIImageView?

Tags: swift, cgcontext

I use `CGContext` in a subclass of `UIView` to draw lines, it works fine when no other views in the `ViewController` on storyboard. However each time putting in an `UIImageView' with an image, it'd cover parts of the lines.

But I wanna draw several lines inside the `UIImageView` or inside the `image`. What should I do?

Would someone help me with it?

Comment: Found this answer looking around for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229916/how-to-procedurally-draw-rectangle-lines-in-swift-using-cgcontext

Comment: Look here for drawing lines on a image in an image view:
[Draw line in UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402902/ios-swift-draw-line-on-uiimage-to-save-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the drawing of an image view. If you want lines to appear in an image view, you must modify the *image* that it contains. Make a new image context, draw the image into it, draw the lines, extract the new image, and assign that image to the image view.

Comment: would you give an example in swift how to draw lines into a UIImage. Thanks.

Comment: Read what I said, please. You don't draw lines into a UIImage. You draw into an image graphics context and extract the image.